# How do I resolve issues when everything in my mac messed up?

Tags: python, bash, macos

my command line tools is set up by homebrew + pip. However, I installed macport trying to get some software but then turns out everything is messed up even after I removed macport... How could I re-set up my Mac for scientific computations including all the necessary command line tools (like vi, bash, they all have errors now and I do not want to solve them one by one)...

I am installing conda though trying to resolve this issue...

Errors include:

```
$Bash
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/bash
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I do not want to list all errors and solve one by one... I just want to reinstall and reset up...

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew unlinkapps
brew linkapps
```

Also there is

```
brew doctor
```

Which shows if there are some problems/confilicts

Comment: I already installed conda, would this conflict with anything in conda?

Comment: @VacassalAlsk I don't know never used conda. I use brew and everything works fine for me.

Comment: great! Bash has no issues then... I did not do updates though, I just do brew cleanup
brew unlinkapps
brew linkapps
, I am bit update would result in some problems in some of my programmes

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a python question...

For future reference, just use the anaconda distribution of python. Don't bother with homebrew or macports. You'll never have to mess with this